# error while reading Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have code to read Excel from c3 language :

```
DataTable dtChildrenData = new DataTable();
            OdbcConnection oConn = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(strSheetPath))
                {
                    oConn = new OdbcConnection();
                    oConn.ConnectionString = @"DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" + strSheetPath + @";DriverId=1046;FIL=excel 12.0;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;";

                    OdbcCommand oComm = new OdbcCommand();
                    oComm.Connection = oConn;
                    oComm.CommandText = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    OdbcDataAdapter oAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(oComm);
                    oConn.Open();
                    oAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    dtChildrenData = ds.Tables[0];
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                oConn.Close();
            }
            return dtChildrenData;
```

But getting this error when **i deploy the web application on IIS.** Wherere as it is running fine locally.

**ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

How to solve this. Please let me know if any information required to answer this question (about configuration)

Remember it is running perfect locally  from VS, when i deploying on IIS on same machine it giving error

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference a DSN that hasn't been created yet it seems. You can create one of these by opening your `Administrative Tools` folder and then starting the `Data Sources (ODBC)` applet.
It seems like you'll then have to create a DSN called *Excel Files*, if you have a machine where this currently works you might be able to copy the settings from that machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the DSNless way by providing a path to the file. see this post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/05/02/uploading-an-excel-file-to-sql-through-an-asp-net-webform.aspx

Comment: This article is really great , but what about the error. why it is coming. I think this error will come in your code also.